# Sorting array and printing out

Tags: java

I am about to sort a 2d array. However there is a certain way of doing this. (Times of running it through, before proceeding to next row)

As you can see, what I have done here, is that I am first sorting row 0, whereafter I am incrementing Before I increment the row, I let it sort the columns `math.pow(m[j].length, 2)`. Is this correct?

Furthermore, is there a smart way of printing out a 2D array from a void method, without using a for loop. The `Arrays.tostring` doesn't help me much ?

```
  public static void sort(int m[][]) {


    int j = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < Math.pow(m[j].length, 2); k++)
    {  
        for (int i = 0; i < m[k].length - 1; i++)
        {

        if (m[i][j] > m[i + 1][j]) 
        {
           int temp = m[i][j];
           m[i][j] = m[i + 1][j];
           m[i + 1][j] = m[i][j];
        }
        }
    }
  System.out.print("The array is " + Arrays.toString(m));   
  }
```

Comment: "is there a smart way of printing out a 2D array from a void method, without using a for loop." - yes: `Arrays.deepToString(m)`

Comment: Thank you, that works for me! 
What does this statement mean ? and why did toString show me matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Furthermore, is there a smart way of printing out a 2D array from a void method, without using a for loop. The Arrays.tostring doesn't help me much ?

Yes. [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) like,

```
System.out.print("The array is " + Arrays.deepToString(m));
```

Finally, your swap is fairly obviously incorrect

```
int temp = m[i][j];
m[i][j] = m[i + 1][j];
m[i + 1][j] = temp; // m[i][j];
```

Comment: i just figured when i got it to print out my result. 
I would want to make my temp an array instead i recon ?

Comment: @Avacay No. Your code (as posted) doesn't use `temp` after you set it.

Comment: array to int doesn't make sense no! 
would i want to create a new array and write the sort to that array?

Comment: @Avacay Why? Unless there is a practical purpose for doubling the amount of memory you need, **don't** do that. All of this is probably moot, [`Arrays.sort(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int[]%29) is *really* fast.

Comment: Uhm okay.. help me out here then. Im sure its a simple solution, and i thought that a temp would be appropriate, as my book used that in an example.

Comment: Furthermore im not sure that im allowed to use the Arrays.sort in my class yet :(

Comment: @Avacay Read my answer again. Look at the last statement compared to yours (in your `if`).